# Is there a way to pass information to an async.js parallel call so I don't have to use global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is there a way to pass information to an async.js parallel call so I don't have to use global variables?

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback){
      setTimeout(function(){
          callback(null, 'one');
      }, 200);
  },
    function(callback){
      setTimeout(function(){
          callback(null, 'two');
      }, 100);
  },
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
  console.log(info)
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
  // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

I would like for the final callback to be aware of the value of "info".  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `info` what is its `scope` and context

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what you're trying to do that a local variable wouldn't solve?

Comment: The final callback only takes two arguments.  I don't know how to give additional information to parallel or the final callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid introducing a global variable you could place it within an enclosure:-

```
(function() {
    var info = "Some info";

    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                callback(null, "one");
            }, 200);
        }, 
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                callback(null, "two");
            }, 100);
        }
    ], 
    function(error, result) {
        console.log(info);
    });

}) ();
```

That way the final callback has access to it but it won't be visible outside of the scope of the anonymous self-executing function that encloses that code.

**EDIT** To do an enclosure in coffeescript:-

```
(() ->
  # my code
)()
```

Comment: I think I might actually be having problems with CoffeeScript scoping.  I pasted in a JavaScript example for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
(function(protectedVariable1,protectedVariable2) {
    //do something with protected variables
})(variable1,variable2);
```